# Suppress Print Dialogue Box in BDC SAP

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I've created an upload program for transaction `FBZ5` using BDC (SHDB recording). Program is working fine but I have only one issue.

This dialogue box is not coming on the recording, no OK_CODE or SCREEN coming in recording of this dialogue box.

If there are 50 records in a file then the PRINT DIALOGUE BOX in opening 50 times.

Is there a way to suppress or bypass this dialogue box and make it pop-up 1 time and send print job to printer of 50 record once?
[image]

Comment: Batch Input ("BDC") works only with SAP GUI screens, not Windows dialogs. I guess you can make it work with SAP GUI Scripting, which scripts SAP GUI too, and you can add code to interact with Windows dialogs (for instance, with language Visual Basic Script).

Comment: Dear @SandraRossi thankyou for the quick response.
So you're saying that there is no way that I can make this Windows Print dialogue from popping up single time instead of 50(if 50 records in file) using ABAP?

Comment: I didn't say that; I don't know if you can do what you expect with Batch Input. Concerning SAP GUI Scripting, you can generate a script and run it from an ABAP program, but first you should make sure that the script can do what you expect.

Comment: I also think it's impossible, batch input is not aware of your printer and which one is installed in the system, it's more a case for GUI Scripting

Comment: Are there any FUNCTION MODULE to suppress this dialogue box ? 
Something like, store all the spool request in one place then send all at once at the end of file?

Comment: This window comes from your operating system, not from SAPGui. So you can't control it from the ABAP side. The reason why it appears 50 times is because SAPGui is generating 50 separate print jobs. So that's where you should look for a solution.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. @Philipp

Comment: Thanks for you inputs everyone.
Appreciated !